# nodejs as WebRTC server

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I need to build solution when client from browser connects to WebRTC server and sends \ receives some data ( for ex audio ). On server side I need to have possibility to control streams. ( for ex. save users audio and send some audio to user)

Is there any solution to build such server side on nodeJS ?

Comment: https://github.com/shinyoshiaki/werift-webrtc

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for video conferencing: https://github.com/Dirvann/mediasoup-sfu-webrtc-video-rooms

and here is an example for recording with the tool: https://github.com/ethand91/mediasoup3-record-demo